# ReactJS several fetch requests with promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I need several fetch requests in my application to fetch data from different collections. Therefore, I wanted to use promises to make it work.
I have never used promises and despite my research on stackoverflow and other websites, I was not able to make it work.

Essentially, I need two fetch requests and I want to save the result of these requests to 2 different states.

This is what I have as of right now:

```
getFormData () {
    fetch('/formdata', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
        .then(res => res.json())
}

getIcons () {
    fetch('/icons', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
        .then(res => res.json())
}

getData () {
    return Promise.all([this.getFormData(), this.getIcons()])
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.getData()
        .then(([formdata, icons]) => {
            console.log(form + "  " + icons);
        })
         .catch(err => console.log('There was an error:' + err))
}
```

But this did not work. 
I also tried putting the promise in my `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, like so:

```
componentDidMount () {
    return Promise.all([this.getFormData(), this.getIcons()])
        .then(([formdata, icons]) => {
            console.log(formdata + "  " + icons);
        })
         .catch(err => console.log('There was an error:' + err))
}
```

But this didn't work eiter.
I would like to save the data from `/formdata` to a state with the same name and the same goes for icons, but in the console it simply returns `undefined undefined`, instead of the formdata and the icons.

Where am I making a mistake in my code? How would I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return Promise object from your methods. As of now you are not returning anything, so it's implicit `undefined`.

Try this:

```
getFormData () {
    return fetch('/formdata', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
        .then(res => res.json())
}

getIcons () {
    return fetch('/icons', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
        .then(res => res.json())
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. It returns [object Object] now, even though, when I just had one fetch request, it returned the data in the proper format. Do you know how I would fix that?

Comment: @A.S.J `[object Object]` is the result of stringification of the object when you log it. Do `console.log(formdata, icons);` to inspect objects properly.

Comment: I just tested it a little more and it always fails at fetching `/icons` and `/formdata` when I reload the page. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: What error does it show when it fails? Check network tab for details.

Comment: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /icons from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/ (ECONNREFUSED).` it gives me the same error for the other fetch request. I read about the error but I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it. To be exact, the error occurs when I upload multiple files to my page and save them with axios post. When I reload the page it gives me this error

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @dfsq's answer, after returning the promises you can update the state within each function:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      formData = {},
      icons: {}
    }
  }

getFormData () {
    return fetch('/formdata', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
    .then(res => res.json(
        this.setState({ formData: res.json })
    ))
}

getIcons () {
    return fetch('/icons', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
    .then(res => res.json(
        this.setState({ icons: res.json })
    ))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. When I try to console.log the state it returns `json() { [native code] }` instead of a value that I could work with. Do you know why this happens and how it can be avoided?

Comment: actually I just managed to fix it by myself, doing this: `.then(res => res.json())
   .then(formdata => this.setState({formdata}, () => console.log(this.state.formdata)))`. Again, thank you very much for taking the time!

Comment: nice glad you solved it, I'd also recommend trying out postman, it's a great tool for testing AJAX requests https://www.getpostman.com/